# Laplacian of coordinate function

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I'm supposed to show

$\nabla^\nu\nabla_\nu x^\mu = -g^{\lambda\nu}\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\nu}$

I think the right approach is to write $\nabla^\nu = g^{\nu\sigma}\nabla_\sigma$ for the first covariant derivative and then just write it all out. However, I can't get things to cancel out which leads me to think I made an elementary mistake somewhere. I also vaguely remember having done a similar question before without a ton of nasty algebra.

I'll appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be fixed, then

$$\nabla_\nu x^\mu = \delta_\nu^{\ \mu}\Rightarrow \nabla^\nu \nabla_\nu x^\mu = g^{\nu\alpha}\nabla_\alpha \delta_\nu^{\ \mu} =g ^{\nu\alpha} \left( \partial_\alpha \delta_\nu^{\ \mu} - \Gamma_{\alpha \nu}^\beta \delta_\beta^{\ \mu}\right) = -g^{\nu\alpha} \Gamma_{\alpha \nu}^\mu$$

Comment: Ah, I see what I was missing! $\nabla_\nu x^\mu = \delta_\nu^\mu$. But I thought $\partial_\nu x^\mu = \delta_\nu^\mu$... That's a bit confusing, I'll look around for explanations.

Comment: $x^\mu$ is a function, so $\nabla_\nu x^\mu = \partial_\nu x^\mu$. @dom_miketa